# Formatting HTML string in red based on condition in c#

Tags: c#, html, .net, string

I have an HTML string where I am getting values  from SQL database as below

```
"100 \n  200 \n 500 \n 1000"
```

I need to replace `<br>` with the new line, also I need to make values in red color if the value is more than or equal to 500

I did the replace it works well as below:

```
  string test = "First line <br/>Second line<br/>First line <br/>Second line";
              Console.WriteLine(test.Replace("<br/>", "\n" ));
```

but how can I do formatting here?

Comment: So, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Also, are you trying to create more HTML or do you want to display this output in the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StringManipulation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sql = "100 \n  200 \n 500 \n 1000";
            string html = GetHTMLForSQL(sql);
        }

        private static string GetHTMLForSQL(string sql)
        {
            int[] values = sql.Split('\n')
                .Select(s => int.Parse(s.Trim()))
                .ToArray();

            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (int val in values)
            {
                html.Append("<p" + (val >= 500 ? " style='color:red;'" : "") + ">" + val + "</p>");
            }
            return html.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

:) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Formatting in the console is probably not how you are imagining it, but if you want to know how to do it, here's code:

```
using System;
namespace tests 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 42;
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
            Console.WriteLine("Another line.");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some Linq. If you're trying to make more HTML, always use classes rather than embedded formatting:

```
var input = "100 \n  200 \n 500 \n 1000";

var output = input = string.Join("", input.Split('\n')
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()))
    .Select(x => $"<span class=\"{(x >= 500 ? "big-number" : "small-number")}\">{x}</span>"));
```

The output of this is:

> <span class="small-number">100</span><span class="small-number">200</span><span class="big-number">500</span><span class="big-number">1000</span>

However, if you want to output to the console, you can do something like this:

```
var output = input.Split('\n')
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim()));

foreach (var element in output)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = element >= 500 
        ? ConsoleColor.Red
        : ConsoleColor.Black;

    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Note that this will explode if any of the values won't parse into an `int`, you should fix that before making this production code.